# Can't send parameters through POST on asp.net vNext app. (beta 3) (MV6, mono, EF7, OSX)

Tags: asp.net, macos, post, mono, asp.net-core-mvc

I hope someone can help me with this...
I'm working on osx on a new small project and "getting to know" the new vNext with MV6 and Entity Framework 7, with mono, kestrel, and using sublime text for the coding...
I have a very simple form:

```
<div class="login-form-outer">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login2", "Account", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", @autocomplete="off" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <h4>Use a Local Account to log in.</h4>
        <hr>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    } </div>
</div>
```

The form submits, the action "Login2" gets called, but **the parameter never reaches the action**...
This is the action BTW.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Login2([FromBody] string Name)
{   
    Console.WriteLine(Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Login2");
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

The only thing the console shows is "Login2", and the redirection also works.

The thing is...
I have a **virtual machine** running a SQL Server database... I installed visual studio 2015 there, and executed the exact same project (shared folder) using **WEB, KESTREL, and IIS**, and they all worked! The parameter gets printed in the console...
So I don't really know where the problem is... is it mono? is it kestrel on OSX?... please help!

I usually work with Rails and Laravel, I'm a noob here...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know with mvc6 but with mvc5 a simple string parameter was sent in the query string.

Did you tried to remove the

```
[FromBody]
```

EDIT:
In MVC5 a simple string parameter can be sent through a form post, a query string or a route value.

Comment: +1. In MVC6 `[FromBody]` should be used for content-type formats like `json` and `xml` which are deserialized by the `InputFormatter`s...for your scenario, the `content-type` would be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and this is NOT handled by the formatters...long story short: remove the `[FromBody]` decoration on your parameter...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, well, like I said, the weird part is that it works if I run it on my virtual machine using visual studio... But anyway, I did what you both recommended and I got this after submitting:
http://s10.postimg.org/m1xpjkygp/Captura_de_pantalla_2015_05_05_a_las_10_22_33.png

I'm even more confused now!  :O

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that last error by setting an env : ASPNET_TEMP on a given folder... Thanks a lot guys.